# Using Jquery 1.4.2 in an ASP.NET app - Error updating JScript IntelliSense

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio-2008, intellisense, javascript-intellisense

I am trying to just add a reference to jquery in my ASP.NET project, and get this when I do: "Error updating JScript IntelliSense ... Object doesn't support this property or method."

I read that I may have to reference vsdoc, but can someone help me with this?

Comment: I have this same problem.  Has anyone resolved it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add reference to vs-doc after you have added jquery.js, this way it works properly with intellisense and also description of jquery elements(using vs-doc).
First reference should be of your core jquery.js file then the rest.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4-vsdoc.js"></script>
```